Crown CM-31W hex wrench size
I have a Crown CM-31W hanging microphone, and it's come loose from the wire loop which bends the hanging cable so the mic points at the stage. Looks like there's a setscrew. I bought the smallest Allen wrenches available at the local Ace Hardware, and they're too big.  Anybody know what size of Allen wrench is needed for this?
The closest thing to a user manual I can find is this https://www.fullcompass.com/common/files/787-CM31Brochure.pdf .
It mentions that the mic has a removable hanger, but doesn't provide instructions on how to remove or reinstall it, nor did it include a wrench.

Giving where Crown comes from, it is probably a metric hex head. You need to measure it. Standard sizes are:
0.7 mm  = 0.028"
0.9 mm  = 0.035"
1.3 mm  = 0.05"
1.5 mm  = 1/16"
2 mm    = 5/64"
And so on.
